# Apache calcite: cast integer to datetime

Tags: apache-beam, apache-calcite, beam-sql

I am using Beam SQL and trying to cast integer to datetime field.

```java
  Schema resultSchema =
    Schema.builder()
          .addInt64Field("detectedCount")
          .addStringField("sensor")
          .addInt64Field("timestamp")
          .build();

  PCollection<Row> sensorRawUnboundedTimestampedSubset = 
    sensorRowUnbounded.apply(
        SqlTransform.query(
          "select PCOLLECTION.payload.`value`.`count` detectedCount, \n"
          + "PCOLLECTION.payload.`value`.`id` sensor, \n"
          + "PCOLLECTION.`timestamp` `timestamp` \n"
          + "from PCOLLECTION "))
    .setRowSchema(resultSchema);
```

For some computation and windowing, I want to convert/cast `timestamp` to `Datetime` field? Please provide some pointers to convert `timestamp` in `resultSchema` to `DateTime`. datatype.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no out of the box way to do that in Beam ([or in Calcite](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/calcite-dev/201808.mbox/%3CF9911776-BEEA-4FFC-8D3A-DABFBBEE7436@apache.org%3E)). Short version - Calcite or Beam have no way of knowing how you actually store the dates or timestamps in the integers. However, assuming you have epoch millis, this should work:

```java
@Test
public void testBlah() throws Exception {
  // input schema, has timestamps as epoch millis
  Schema schema = Schema.builder().addInt64Field("ts").addStringField("st").build();

  DateTime ts1 = new DateTime(2019, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12);
  DateTime ts2 = new DateTime(2019, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12);

  PCollection<Row> input =
    pipeline
      .apply(
          "createRows",
          Create.of(
              Row.withSchema(schema).addValues(ts1.getMillis(), "two").build(),
              Row.withSchema(schema).addValues(ts2.getMillis(), "twelve").build()))
      .setRowSchema(schema);

  PCollection<Row> result =
    input.apply(
      SqlTransform.query(
          "SELECT \n"
          + "(TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00' + ts * INTERVAL '0.001' SECOND) as ts, \n"
          + "st \n"
          + "FROM \n"
          + "PCOLLECTION"));

  // output schema, has timestamps as DateTime
  Schema outSchema = Schema.builder().addDateTimeField("ts").addStringField("st").build();
  PAssert.that(result)
    .containsInAnyOrder(
        Row.withSchema(outSchema).addValues(ts1, "two").build(),
        Row.withSchema(outSchema).addValues(ts2, "twelve").build());
  pipeline.run();
}
```

Alternatively you can always do it in java, not in SQL, just apply a custom `ParDo` to the output of the `SqlTransform`. In that `ParDo` extract the integer timestamp from the `Row` object, convert it to [`DateTime`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#DateTime(long)) and then emit it, e.g. as part of another row with a different schema.